# Javascript is not doing sum of all records

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to do the sum of all cart items but it is not doing it.
It is showing only the sum of first or last item added in the cart.

What is the issue i cannot understand. I have tried by moving code in the java but no use.

Suppose i have 2 items.

Item1 total is = 100
Item2 total is = 200

Total should be 300 not only the 1 items total.

Below is my code.

Thanks in advance

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>

<table class="table mg-bottom-45 refresh" id="myTable">
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th class="product-cart-price"><span>PRICE</span></th>
    <th class="product-cart-price"><span>TOTAL</span></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>

<tbody>
<?php
include ('inc/db.php');

$citem  = "select * from orders_temp
where user_id = 1 order by id
";
$ciquery    = $dba2->query($citem);
while ($cifetch = $ciquery->fetch_assoc()){
    $orderID    =   $cifetch['id'];
    $userID =   $cifetch['user_id'];
?>
    <td class="product-cart-thumbnail">
    <input name="quantity" type="text" data-id="<?php echo $orderID; ?>" 
    data-price="" value="<?php echo $cifetch['qty']; ?>"
    class="un quant" /> 
    </td>


    <td class="product-cart-thumbnail">
    <input name="quantity" type="text" data-id="<?php echo $orderID; ?>" 
    data-price="<?php echo $cifetch['price']; ?>"
    value="<?php echo $cifetch['price']; ?>" class="un pricex" />
    </td>


<?php } ?>
    <td class="totalAmount"></td>
</tbody>
</table>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  updatexx<?php echo $orderID; ?>();
  function updatexx<?php echo $orderID; ?>() {
    var sumx = '';
    $('#myTable > tbody  > tr').each(function() {
      var quantityx = $(this).find('.quant').val(); 
      var pricex = $(this).find('.pricex').attr('data-price').replace(',', '.');
      var amountx = (quantityx * pricex).toFixed(3);

      sumx += amountx;
    });
    $('.totalAmount').text(sumx);
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: sumx should be declare as number var sumx = 0

Comment: @Rishab  i tried this but it doesnt work it shows the same last items sum not all and also puts an extra 0 in front of last items total amount

Comment: please add the HTML output of your php code will help us to resolve problem

Comment: Why does your function name contain the order ID to begin with? And why is that code generated only after the loop? If you had a valid reason for creating multiple such functions to handle different IDs, then surely this would belong _inside_ the loop as well?

Comment: @usman610 Can you let us know how many times your loop $('#myTable > tbody  > tr').each(function() {}) is being iterating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is the solution with some changes in my code.
Now it is working perfectly as required. It is doing the sum of all items and everything what i want.

```
<table class="table mg-bottom-45 refresh" id="myTable">
<tbody>
<?php
$i = 0;
//error_reporting(0);
$ses_mem    =   1;
include ('inc/db.php');

$citem      = "select id, user_id, qty, org_price  from orders_temp 
where user_id = '".$ses_mem."' and status = 1
order by id
";
$ciquery    = $dba2->query($citem);
while ($cifetch = $ciquery->fetch_assoc()){
    $orderID    =   $cifetch['id'];
?>

<tr>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  updatexx<?php echo $orderID; ?>();
  function updatexx<?php echo $orderID; ?>() {
var sumx = 0.000;
var quantity;
$('#myTable > tbody  > tr').each(function() {

  quantity = $(this).find('.quant').val();  
  var price = $(this).find('.pricex').attr('data-price').replace(',', '.');
  var amountx = (quantity * price);
      var munterx = amountx.toFixed(3);

  sumx += amountx;
  $(this).find('.amountx<?php echo $orderID; ?>').text('' + munterx);
});
    var sumxx = sumx.toFixed(3);
$('.total').text(sumxx);
  }
});
</script>

        <td class="single-qty" style="border: 0;">
        <input id="<?php echo $orderID; ?>" name="quantity" type="text" 
        data-id="<?php echo $orderID; ?>" 
        data-price="" value="<?php echo $cifetch['qty']; ?>"
        class="un quant" />
        </td>

        <td class="product-cart-price pricex" data-price="<?php echo $cifetch['org_price']; ?>">
        </td>

        <td class="amountx<?php echo $orderID; ?>">
        </td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
</tbody>
</table>

<table class="table">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Sub Total (RS)</td>
<td class="text-right"
    style="text-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #999999; font-weight: bold;
    color: black; direction: rtl;">
        <span class="total">
        </span>
    </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

First, please make sure that your loop is running multiple times (same number of products in cart).

```
$('#myTable > tbody  > tr').each(function() {})
```

so that the above loop iterate exact number times as per required.

You should make some changes in code as follows:

```
var sumx = 0.00;
```

and in loop code should be

```
 sumx += parsefloat(amountx);
```

Comment: @Rishab that does not make much sense. You could theoretically solve _everything_ by just commenting. If anyone has a suggestion on how to fix the presented issue, then creating an answer is fine. (If there is still stuff to clarify before the question _can_ be answered, then that should be done via comments.)

Comment: this solution doesnt help

Comment: @usman610 neither does your problem description much. We don’t have your database or any other part of your server-side setup available, so we can not re-create the exact output of your PHP script. You should show the generated HTML instead to begin with in a case like this.

Comment: @Rishab  I know brother 1266. but there may be various reasons for code failure.